# Retrieve Data from JSON into List View

Tags: android, json, listview

I hope many developers already worked with this and some of them also has made changes, so here we go:

I am trying to make **Multi Level List View using JSON**, and using this tutorial for *Client Side coding:*

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

I am able to get List of Albums using this JSON:

```
[
{
"id":1,
"name":"127 Hours",
"songs_count":14
},
{
"id":2,
"name":"Adele 21",
"songs_count":11
}
]
```

but **not getting List of Songs** under that *Album*

and to get List of Songs **i have tried two kinds of JSON**

first this:

```
{
"id":1,
"album":"127 Hours",
"songs":
[
{
"id":1,
"name":"Never Hear Surf Music Again",
"duration":"5:52"
},
{
"id":2,
"name":"The Canyon",
"duration":"3:01"
}
],
"id":2,
"album":"Adele 21",
"songs":
[
{
"id":1,
"name":"Rolling In The Deep",
"duration":"03:48"
}
]
}
```

second this:

```
[
{

    "id":1,
    "album":"127 Hours",
    "songs":[
      {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Never Hear Surf Music Again",
      "duration":"5:52"
      }
    ]
}, {
    "id":2,
    "album":"Adele 21",
    "songs":[
      {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Rolling In The Deep",
      "duration":"03:48"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

**Note:** I wanna use same code to make same kind of Multi Level ListView, but with the use of JSON only, not with the use of PHP Classes or is it possible to use only single JSON to show list of Albums and Songs, if possible so please write that JSON for me..

Comment: can we have your parsing code that you have coded to parse this jSon.

Comment: same code, written in TUTORIAL, nothing different @Aarun

Comment: @AbrahimNeil: can you share your java code.. what you did for parsing this JSON and what you tried for your functionality...

Comment: @AbrahimNeil give you json file link let me try this.

Comment: @Aarun i guess you can copy above written JSON and use your server or dropbox to test

Comment: @AbrahimNeil: try gson library to parse your JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

JSON Parser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Fragment class showing Listview:

```
public static class EventFragment extends ListFragment {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList;
        private String url_all_events = //url goes here;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String CONNECTION_STATUS = "success";
        private static final String TABLE_EVENT = "Event";
        private static final String pid = "pid";
        private static final String COL_GROUP = "Group";
        private static final String COL_NAME = "Event_Name";
        private static final String COL_DESC = "Event_Desc";
        private static final String COL_DATE = "Event_Date";
        private static final String COL_TIME = "Event_Time";

        JSONArray Events = null;

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public EventFragment() {
        }

        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            new LoadAllEvents().execute();

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // Lauching the Event details screen on selecting a single event
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid))
                            .getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            EventDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra(pid, ID);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }

        class LoadAllEvents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Just a moment...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_events,
                        "GET", params);

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(CONNECTION_STATUS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        Events = json.getJSONArray(TABLE_EVENT);
                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < Events.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject evt = Events.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            id = evt.getString(pid);
                            group = evt.getString(COL_GROUP);
                            name = evt.getString(COL_NAME);
                            desc = evt.getString(COL_DESC);
                            date = evt.getString(COL_DATE);
                            time = evt.getString(COL_TIME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(pid, id);
                            map.put(COL_GROUP, group);
                            map.put(COL_NAME, name);
                            map.put(COL_DESC, desc);
                            map.put(COL_DATE, date);
                            map.put(COL_TIME, time);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            eventsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Options are not available or server is down.
                        // Dismiss the loading dialog and display an alert
                        // onPostExecute
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                                eventsList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                        pid, COL_GROUP, COL_NAME, COL_DATE, COL_TIME },
                                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.group, R.id.name, R.id.header,
                                        R.id.title2 });

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

Activity details class:

```
public class EventDetails extends Activity {

    String pid;
    TextView EvtName, EvtDesc, EvtDate, EvtTime, Header;
    ImageView logo;

    private String url_event_details = "http://centrubook.eu.pn/eventDetails.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String CONNECTION_STATUS = "success";
    private static final String TABLE_EVENT = "Event";
    private static final String COL_PID = "pid";
    private static final String COL_NAME = "Event_Name";
    private static final String COL_DESC = "Event_Desc";
    private static final String COL_DATE = "Event_Date";
    private static final String COL_TIME = "Event_Time";

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eventdetails);

        // ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        EvtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BombaName);
        EvtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BombaDesc);
        EvtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BombaDate);
        EvtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BombaTime);
        logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BombaLogo);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        pid = i.getStringExtra(COL_PID);
        new getEventDetails().execute();
    }

    class getEventDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String name, desc, date, time;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EventDetails.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Just a moment...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_event_details,
                        "GET", params);

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(CONNECTION_STATUS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray eventsObj = json.getJSONArray(TABLE_EVENT);

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject details = eventsObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    name = details.getString(COL_NAME);
                    desc = details.getString(COL_DESC);
                    date = details.getString(COL_DATE);
                    time = details.getString(COL_TIME);

                } else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    EvtName.setText(name);
                    EvtDesc.setText(desc);
                    EvtDate.setText(date);
                    EvtTime.setText(time);
                    logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.events);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```